# telerik grid not showing proper date

Tags: asp.net-mvc, telerik-grid

I am using telerik extensions for Asp.Net MVC from last 1 year.

Earlier I noticed that there is some major difference between the date at server & in Sql Server & date that is rendered in telerik column.
Attached is the screen shot showing the date difference.

Can you suggest any centralized solution to overcome this problem, because till now have grids at lot more places & this issues is burning my heads.

After some googling I found that browser usually adds some time offset of browser time zone before rendering a date in javascript, so my simple solution was to subtract that browser time zone offset from the date I am getting.

So I added a javascript function to handle this but still the solution works in one time zones but for other it shows a lot more difference.

My server is located in Central time zone whereas users are all accross other timezones in US.

Can any one suggest me any solution for this?

here is my javascript function

```
function parseToServerTimezone(date) {
        if (date != null) {
            var clientOffset = new Date().getTimezoneOffset();
            var newDate = new Date(date);
            newDate.setMinutes(date.getMinutes() - clientOffset);
            return $.telerik.formatString("{0:g}", date);
        }
        return date;
    }
```

and here is how it is used in grid, all my grids are ajax bound here

```
column.Bound(m => m.CapCycleStartDate).Title(Html.Resource("CapCycleStartDate")).ClientTemplate("<#= parseToServerTimezone(CapCycleStartDate) #>").Width(18).HtmlAttributes(new { align = "center" });
```

Thanks.

Comment: Mandar, have you seen this discussion about Telerik grids and timezones http://www.telerik.com/community/forums/aspnet-mvc/grid/grids-and-dates.aspx? If not, it may be helpful.

Comment: @Mandar It's not that the "browser usually adds some time offset of browser time zone", but that Date functions in Javascript always return values representing the browser's local time. You can calculate a time zone offset and subtract it before displaying your times, but historical dates may be subject to a different daylight saving time offset. I convert times to the user's (not browser's) local time zone before sending them to Javascript. In AJAX-bound grid rows, I handle the OnRowDataBound event, format my date explicitly, and replace the cell value. All my time data are stored as UTC.